# Android - Optimizing application performance by image compression

Tags: java, android, performance, compression

I am working on an application that are loaded with large png images.
I started to optimize the app performance by reducing the size of each image to it's original size in phone.

I am using adobe photoshop . I was wondered how would be better to output the image file ? save it like normal or use "save for web" and compress it to PNG-8 or PNG-24 .

what do you advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use some of compress tools like http://tinypng.com or http://compressor.io, android studio has bundled some image optimization, if you want to know more watch Google I/O session about it.

http://youtu.be/r_LpCi6DQME

Comment: Thanks i will try , by the way i don't care about image size , i just want it to load faster and use low RAM memory , adobe Photoshop "save for web" won't do the work ? is it good enough ?

Comment: low ram memory what that means? well you can try yourself to compare size of images when you just save it from photoshop or with lossy/lossless compression ... i use in my apps WebP format, so that's another suggestion..and if you can accept my answer, thanks